# Vaccines Research - A theorical question just out of curiosity

Tags: vaccination, research

First of all I'd like to point out that I'm not in any medical field, nor I've the adeguate specific formation to know enough about the topic, so this question is going to be more like a "What if" question out of curiosity. I'll let the experts fill the gaps.

Since we know that when we introduce a new virus into the human body, the 
immune response tries, (and hopefully succeed), to create an antibody, and that
such antibody is specific for that virus and can be re-created in case of later need,
I'm assuming that it has a specific "recipe" stored somewhere in our body, presumably in our dna, for our body to use when needed.

Would it be possibile then, to track those changes in the dna to identify what's actually the recipe of the antibody?
From my field of knowledge I'm pretty sure that with enough data and a proper AI, we could
eventually track down the specific changes.

Once we have those, couldn't we inject those edits into a new subject (with CRISPS?) or look at the composition of the antibody to reproduce it artificially?

Thanks for your time

Comment: I'm not much further than you in terms of medical knowlege but: the information that gives us immunity is stored in particular cells (memory cells). They easily undergo mutation (which is how they "learn" to adapt to infections). This is something our immune system is very good at, and we use this with "normal" vaccination. But everyone's immune system will recognize someone else's cells as foreign and attack them (and sometimes even own cells). So you'd need to be very careful to find DNA parts that code antibodies that are sufficiently sensitive in detecting the virus, and specific to...

Comment: ... not attack the new host - which the original memory cell never knew (so was never optiized to be specific), so we don't know whether there's a cross-sensitivity.